# Create a scale key for jvectormap region colors

Tags: jvectormap

I'd like to create a key to my map that shows the values associated with the different colors, as at the bottom of the drawing:

[image]

I can make a series of boxes easily enough. Is there a method somewhere I can input a value to get the color back that the map would use for that value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need a map object. If you have created a map with `jvm.WorldMap` constructor you have it already, otherwise if you have created a map using jQuery wrapper you can do:

```
var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Then to convert the value to color do the following:

```
var color = map.series.regions[0].scale.getValue(someValue);
```

Comment: Thanks. Hmm... I'm getting a weird result when I put in zero: http://jsfiddle.net/sprugman/fkRnC/6/. I would expect to get the value that I put in for regionStyle.initial.fill.

Comment: @sprugman You get a weird result just because the 0 value is outside of the range scale which is 25..400 in your example.

Comment: But the data will always to be > 0, but I still want the scale to start at 0.

Comment: @sprugman Than you need to provide `min` parameter equal to 0 for the data series.