# Add Legend to jVectorMap

Tags: jvectormap

I am updating our application to use jVectorMap instead of a Flash. Some of the maps need the countries to be colored differently. This is pretty simple to create.

```
<div id="world-map-color" style="width: 900px; height: 600px;"></div>
<script>
    var myData = {
                  "AF": 36.63,
                  "RU": 11.58,
                  "US": 158.97
                 };

    $('#world-map-color').vectorMap({
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        regionStyle: {
            initial: { fill: "#7C96A1" },
            hover: { fill: "#A0D1DC" }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: myData,
                scale: ['#B0ADF7', '#0D0885'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

The resulting map:

[image: Color Map]

However, I'd like to add some kind of legend/key to say what the scale of the colors are. Something like the following:

[image: Example Lengend]

Additionally, that example legend (from Flash) allowed the user to change the scaling for the colors using those arrows on the top. So it'd be nice if that was possible as well.

Does anyone know if any parts of these are possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic thing is necessary to achieve is the generation of the colorful scale. For that see the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147104/create-a-scale-key-for-jvectormap-region-colors/13168628#13168628) I have answered recently.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I am guessing this means their isn't a native feature to display a legend? (I believe you are the author of jVectorMap? Very nice app btw).

Comment: @R Not yet, but I have plans to implement this feature in on of the next versions.

Comment: Cool! Oh, BTW, is there a way to easily get the smallest and largest values in the region (e.g. the biggest and smallest values in `myData` above - which would be 11.58 and 158.97)?

Comment: @RachelG. Try `map.series.regions[0].scale.minValue` and `map.series.regions[0].scale.maxValue`

Comment: Worked with a normalizeFunction of linear. Ty